# Open Group Policy Management Console (gpmc) for Another Domain

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to open a gpmc for another domain. We have 2 AD Domains A and B. There are no trusts between them. My Computer is joined to Domain A and I want to open a gpmc for domain B.

For DSA (AD Users and Computers) this seems to be possible like this:

`runas.exe /netonly /user:<Domain B>\<Domain B User> "mmc dsa.msc /domain=<Domain B>"`

but when I try to run this for gpmc the following error comes up:

[image: error when trying to open gpmc for domain B on a computer on domain A]

I probably do not have access to the logs of either domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but with the help of a colleague we came to a solution. The GPMC has an option called trust detection (View -> Options -> General).

[image: trust detection disabled]

Once this options is disabled, the GPMC has to be closed so that this option is saved. If you then start the GPMC via

`runas.exe /netonly /user:<Domain B>\<Domain B User> "mmc gpmc.msc /domain=<Domain B>"`

the forest from domain B can be added and you can configure your GPOs as you normally would.

Answer (score 2):

This is working as expected and is not supposed to work. The GPMC console is designed to try to get a operational token for the PDC of the domain environment wherever you are opening the same. Because PDC(*primary domain controller role holder in a domain* ) is supposed to have the most recent copy of the group policies (*but sometimes this is not true due to delayed replication etc.*) So when you try to connect to GPMC of another domain it connects and sends a Kereros request which fails to get a ticket(*to be considered same as token i mentioned above.*)  .

If you take a network trace in both the cases you will see that there is a TGT request to get a ticket for SPN ldap/(domain A) from the domain B domain controller which is not possible because you do not have trust between the domains. This fails with "KerberosV5:KRB_ERROR  - KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN (7)" . This is the moment you see the access is denied error as shown in screenshot . I hope that provides clarity on your query .